# TensorFlow DNN on Colab (ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset)

Tags: python, tensorflow, validation, keras, callback

I am trying to follow this blog [post](https://github.com/AntonsRuberts/datascience_marketing/blob/master/DNN%20vs%20BG_NBD%20for%20CLV.ipynb). I want to predict customer lifetime value using a DNN. I am running into an error when I run the code for fitting the DNN model to my dataset. I am pretty new to machine learning and I have tried to do due diligence in understanding what the code is doing.

```
#DNN
def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(X_train.columns), ]),
    layers.Dropout(0.3),
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)

    model.compile(loss='mse',
            optimizer=optimizer,
            metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    
    return model

# The patience parameter is the amount of epochs to check for improvement
early_stop = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20)

model = build_model()
early_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    epochs=EPOCHS, validation_split = 0.2, verbose=0, 
                    callbacks=[early_stop, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])

#Predicting
dnn_preds = model.predict(X_test).ravel()
```

I have seen a few similar questions and the answer was, that X_train has to be empty, but X_train is a really big table.

The Error Code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-0fda30035cb2> in <module>()
      3                     epochs=1000,
      4                     verbose=0,
----> 5                     validation_split = 0.2)
      6 #                    callbacks=[early_stop, tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots()])
      7 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1193         logs = tf_utils.sync_to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)
   1194         if logs is None:
-> 1195           raise ValueError('Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.')
   1196         epoch_logs = copy.copy(logs)
   1197 

ValueError: Expect x to be a non-empty array or dataset.
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are using the wrong type for X_train.  I do not think model.fit can accept whatever your table is (pandas table?).  Most likely you want to pass it a numpy array of shape [Number of Examples (rows in the table), Input Features (columns in table)].  Have a look at the documentation for model.fit.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit